# div elements are not showing and footer is placed above non showing divs when viewing in mobile size format

Tags: html, css

```css
#contact-info .icon-detail{
  float: none;
  width:100%;
  height:250px;
  border-bottom: #444 solid 1px;
}
```

```html
    <section id="contact-info" class="bg-dark1">
          <div class="icon-detail">
            <i class="fas fa-hotel fa-3x"></i>
            <h2>Location</h2>
            <p>50 Main Street , 10th street , boston</p>
          </div>

          <div class="icon-detail">
            <i class="fas fa-phone fa-3x"></i>
            <h2>Phone Number</h2>
            <p>(555) 555-5555</p>
          </div>
          
          <div class="icon-detail">
            <i class="fas fa-envelope fa-3x"></i>
            <h2>Email</h2>
            <p>frontdesk@hotelbt.co</p>
          </div>
      </section>

      <div class="clr"></div>

    <footer id="main-footer">
      <p>Hotel BT &copy; 2019,All rights reserved</p>
    </footer>

  </body>
</html>
```

div elements are not showing and footer is placed above non showing divs when viewing in mobile size format...
when in full screen it looks fine ,but when i look for mobile view i am getting this fault

Comment: can you show your code please ?

Comment: the css part is under @media query...